# How to draw HTML table having contain result of SQL query and send to mail in Shell script

Tags: html, oracle, shell, unix

I want to draw HTML table contain record of SQL query and send to mail in shell script.
Here is the shell script:-

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
out=$(for id in 1 2 3 4
      do
      sqlplus -s <user>/<password>@<db> <<EOF
      spool out.txt;
      select id, count(*) from <table> where id=${id};
      spool off;
      exit;
      EOF
      done)

 echo ${out} > out.txt
(uuencode out.txt out.txt)| cat out.txt| mailx -s "Before" abc@xyz.com
```

And I am getting output of the query in different format not HTML table format. The table format should be like this (in the table with the border line)

```
ID            Results
        Before      After
1          12         15
2          27         30 
3          45         52
```

Could you please help me to draw HTML table of this record.

Comment: You can start from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742656/within-a-pl-sql-procedure-wrap-a-query-or-refcursor-in-html-table https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_seven.htm#i1043351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside SQL query need to use `SET MARKUP HTML ON`and in spool extension file as `.html` then we can get output of the query in html format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the html code after and before your consult , and concatenate inside your sql. Like :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#start table
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>BEFORE></th><th>AFTER</th></thead><tbody><th>" > out.txt
out=$(for id in 1 2 3 4
      do
      sqlplus -s <user>/<password>@<db> <<EOF
      SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF PAGESIZE 0
      spool out.txt;
      select '<td>'||ID||'</td><td>' || BEFORE || '</td><td>' || BEFORE || '</td>' from <table> where id=${id};
      spool off;
      exit;
      EOF
      done)

 echo ${out} >> out.txt

 #finish table 
 echo "</th></tbody></table> >> out.txt

(uuencode out.txt out.txt)| cat out.txt| mailx -s "Before" abc@xyz.com
```

*I didn't test the code

Comment: Thanks for give me some hints. But I tested it then get the ID & counts in </td> patterns like `'<TD>'||ID||'</TD><TD>'||COUNT(ID)||'</
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<td>4</td><td>453</td><td></td>` not in the HTML table format that I want.

Comment: Did you change all code ? I put some echo above and below your query result.  Can you post a out.txt result ?

Comment: Can you post a out.txt result ?

Comment: ID After-----   ------ 01 15  ID After --------  ---------- 02 30 ID After --------  ---------- 03 52 ............ like this in out.txt that i am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I reproduced the problem in my environment

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#start table
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>BEFORE</th><th>AFTER</th></tr></thead><tbody><th>" > out.html


rot_sqlplus(){

sqlplus -s /nolog <<SQLPLUSEND
conn user/passwd@database
SET HEADING OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
select '<tr><td>'||ID|| '</td><td>' || BEFORE || '</td><td>' || BEFORE || '</td></tr>' from teste where id=$1;
quit
SQLPLUSEND

}

out=$(for id in 1 2 3 4
     do
        rot_sqlplus $id
      done)

 echo ${out} >> out.html

#finish table 
echo "</th></tbody></table>" >> out.html

cat out.html
```

result to out.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>BEFORE</th>
            <th>AFTER</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <th>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td><td>12</td><td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td><td>27</td><td>27</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td><td>45</td><td>45</td>
            </tr>
        </th>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View in Browser

[image]

Comment: But it should not come in browser. It will come in the mail content.

Comment: Of course, independently the solution you choose, your email client needs to be able to read HTML , like gmail, Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: Thanks a lot but The table format like above as I've mentioned above in the question not like that you've drawn in this answer.